# Populating Data from NSMutableArray in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have three arrays and I have copied all these arrays into a single array. All these three arrays are arrays of dictionaries.All arrays has a field called picture, but that pictures is coming from different sources- URL in one array, data in other and files in the third one.

Say, Array1 has dictionaries with a key - picture and its loaded from `NSURL`.
Similarly, Array2 and Array3 has dictionaries with same key name - picture and loaded from `ContentofFiles` and `NSData`.

Now, I want to populate tableview, of course,m having `Custom UITableViewCell`,  it has image view as its content view. To load that image, what should I do.

I was doing this thing..

```
NSURL *url  = [NSURL URLWithString:[[contactList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"picture"]];
cell.contactImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
```

But, this will crash if `cell.contactImageView.image` don’t receive image from NSURL.So, what should I do? Any help, will be appreciated

But,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot buddies for your Quick reply,especially @skram, due to your suggestion,my tableview performance has increased much. the Question, that I have asked,the better answer that I have thought of is using `iskindofClass`. If image is coming from any class, on a condition ,we can check from where that image was coming and populate our image accordingly.

```
if ([[[contactList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"picture"] isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]) 
    {
        cell.contactImageView.image = [[contactList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"picture"];
    }
    else if ([[[contactList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"picture"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) 
    {
        cell.contactImageView.image = [[contactList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"picture"];
    }
    else if([[[contactList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"picture"] isKindOfClass:[NSURL class]])
    {
        [cell.contactImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[contactList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"picture"]]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
    }
```

Now, I’m able to populate the tableview properly.Once again thanx to `scram`.

Answer (score 3):

all you is to check if the received image is null and if it is, then set a template photo image called no photo like a photo on facebook when no profile picture is selected

```
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
    if (img)
       cell.contactImageView.image = img;
    else
       cell.contactImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"no_photo.png"];
```

Comment: You typed the same thing I was going to type (so +1 to you), but I was also going to add the detail that for server-dependent stuff like this (where things can fail or be nil unexpectedly), and just in general, one should ***not*** put so much into one single line of Objective C code.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann when ever you see  some post need modification, just edit it, i care about idear and you should edit my post

Comment: I'll edit posts to fix grammar and spelling problems but not massive code changes.  There's no problems with your code snippet, but in Surya's, s/he is doing an objectForKey on the same line as an objectAtIndex, plus a imageWithData after a dataWIthCOntentsOfURL (and no error checking in any of it).  No wonder there's a crash!

Comment: @Michael Dautermann: Crash is only if that image is not coming from URL, else it running good, if you want to suggest anything,u’r welcome.

Comment: @The Saad: But it crashes in this line NSURL *url  = [NSURL URLWithString:[[contactList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"picture"]];, as I think that “URLWithString” is not getting proper URL, its getting data.So, what to do now?

Comment: this crashes then may be due to index of array or nil value returned from array

Answer (score 1):

If these images are retrieved from the net, i would suggest not using `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]`.

You should be using a non blocking method, that loads images asynchronously. Using this method on numerous rows in a table will cause performance issues.

Here's my recommendation , use the [SDWebImage Library](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) . Easy to use, and even easier to install.

Once you add the library to your project, simply `#import` the `UIImageView+WebCache.h` class usage example is below.

```
 [cell.contactImageView.image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[contactList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"picture"]]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more key in dictionary which will specify from where to take photo and accordingly you can provide image to cell.contactImageView, if you want to provide image from different sources.